# Abas Asp.Net MVC x Asp.Net WebForms Ajax Toolkit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, webforms, ajaxtoolkit

Alguém conhece alguma técnica para criação e manipulação de abas do lado servidor usando o ***AJAX*** com ***Aps.Net MVC***? Procuro alguma coisa bem similar as abas do ***Asp.NET WebForms AjaxToolKit***, que da para manipular as abas no **code-behind** e seu envio de dados ao salvar informações é via ***AJAX***.

Estou procurando isso para não ficar manipulando as abas do lado **Javascript**, por segurança mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar, no MVC não existe *Code Behind*.

Em segundo lugar, a manipulação de abas, entre mortos e feridos, é uma abstração de um código JS aplicado a eventos dentro de um HTML de uma forma controlada.

Em terceiro lugar, não é inseguro manipular o JS no ASP.NET MVC porque ele foi projetado pra isso: pra que você possa colocar JS à vontade na sua aplicação sem necessariamente comprometer a segurança.

A maneira de se comunicar com o `Controller` usando eventos AJAX é implementando `Actions` e chamando essas `Actions` com componentes que implementem isso, como o jQuery, por exemplo. A ideia da Microsoft fazendo isso é se aproximar do novo padrão utilizado pelos novos Frameworks como Ruby on Rails, Django e Node.js, que se baseiam apenas nas rotas para buscar e/ou processar uma informação.

Há uma série de bons componentes usando JS e CSS que implementam isso, até bem melhor que o AJAX Control Toolkit, como o [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) e o [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

Comment: Sim, é o que eu estou fazendo. Citei o code behind como exemplo. Estou chamando os controles para trazer a informação via ajax e manipular pelo jquery e etc. Falei em segurança pelo fato de que você consegue ver o código javascript e manipular suas abas já que estou montando do lado cliente somente com a informação vinda do controller. Att. Existe alguma maneira melhor de montar essas abas do lado servidor e já trazer o necessário, alem dos dados para manipular isso do lado cliente ?

Comment: Existe. É uma combinação de `ActionResult`s com [`RemoteValidation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx).

Comment: Boa, valeu, vou dar uma estudada nisso.